# Why can i not run "support show db-status free %" on a remote server with paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, remote-server, fabric

I have tried paramiko and fabric. I get the same error message and i have no clue why this command never runs successfully.

```
import paramiko

client - paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname, port, username, password)
stdin, stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("support show db-status free %")
print(stdout.readline())
```

I am using test server login information to connect to the host. So i need to connect to the server with this information that is in no way connected to my pc and i get this error message after every run.

```
ERROR: Incorrect number of arguments
Usage: cli_wrapper
```

ill gladly provide more insight if needed

Comment: What kind of system are you connecting to? Is it a router or some kind of network hardware? Is it a general-purpose computer? What operating system does it run?

Comment: Can you do `ssh username@hostname support show db-status free %`? (as one line, not two).

Answer (score 1):

Give input parameters like this,

```
ssh.connect(host, port, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
```

Comment: I get no output at all. I print(client.stderr.readlines(), client.stdout.readline()) and i get back an array with the two errors i showed for stderr along with an empty array for stdout.